# Error when segregating sites of vcf using vcfR::seg.sites "Error in latag2n(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector"

Tags: r, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a large vcf file from next gen sequencing. I am not able to segregate DNA sites using the seg.sites function.

I am able to load my vcf file using `Discolor<-read.vcfR("file_name")`, but when I try to find segregated sites in my DNA using `seg.sites(Discolor)` I get `Error in latag2n(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector`.

When I do class(Discolor), I get the following.

```
[1] "vcfR"
attr(,"package")
[1] "vcfR"
```

Comment: The vcfR package does not seem to have a function called `seg.sites()`. The reference manual mentions `ape::seg.sites()`. Is that what you're using? Are you sure you're applying the function correctly? `read.vcfR()` returns an object of class vcfR-class, which is a complex object with several data slots, while `seg.sites()` requires a matrix or list as input.